# Testcafe: Testing by polling

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is there a way to test a page by polling it data ? We have server delay and would require to reload the page now and then to get the correct data.

Initially i was thinking about adding a custom method to a selector and perform reload there but it was not successful since it return the value long before the page is done loading.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

The choice depends on your requirements. One way is to write this code:

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture('My fixture')
    .page('https://www.google.com');

const reloadPage = new ClientFunction(() => location.reload(true));

async function waitForElement ({ numOfRetries = 15 } = {}) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfRetries; i++) {
        if (await Selector('#polling-data').exists)
            return true;

        await reloadPage();
    }

    return false;
}

test('My Test', async t => {
    await t.expect(await waitForElement()).ok();
});
```

This test code will be reloading the page a specified number of times trying to find the element with the `polling-data` identifier in DOM. Once the element is found, you will be able to assert values of the element properties as needed.